# Facebook Audience Network invalid URL scheme crash

Tags: ios, facebook-audience-network

Recently, we've been experiencing crashes when user taps on some ads with 'Shop Now' call to action.

> Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
>   The specified URL has an unsupported scheme. Only HTTP and HTTPS URLs are supported.

Stack trace

> Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
>
> 0  CoreFoundation 0x183a661c0 __exceptionPreprocess
>
> 1  libobjc.A.dylib 0x1824a055c objc_exception_throw
>
> 2  CoreFoundation 0x183a66108 -[NSException initWithCoder:]
>
> 3  SafariServices  0x191d7020c -[SFSafariViewController
>   initWithURL:entersReaderIfAvailable:]
>
> 4  MyApp           0x100653064 +[FBAdSafariViewController
>   presentSafariViewControllerWithURL:withRootViewController:withDelegate:]
>   (FBAdSafariViewController.m:54) 
>   5  MyApp            0x1005cd9bc -[FBAdCommandProcessor openLinkInApp:]
>   (FBAdCommandProcessor.m:225)
>
> 6  MyApp            0x1005ccf04 -[FBAdCommandProcessor
>   processCommand:withExtraData:adDataModel:completionHandler:]
>   (FBAdCommandProcessor.m:128)
>
> 7  MyApp            0x1005d9310 -[FBANNativeAdAdapter
>   onClickForViewController:withExtraData:] (FBANNativeAdAdapter.m:118)
>
> 8 MyApp              0x1005ed058 __46-[FBDisplayAdController
>   notifyAdViewPresented]_block_invoke.145 (FBDisplayAdController.m:321)
>
> 9  MyApp  0x100646c30 -[FBNativeAdhandleTap:withEvent:] (FBNativeAd.m:662)

It obviously crashes when it attempts to open SFSafariViewController with an URL with non http(s) scheme.

The stack trace is from fabric. I haven't been able to catch the exception in the debugger (since it occurs on specific ads), so I can't actually know the URLs of the problematic ad(s).

Also, URL is not a public property of the FBNativeAd class, so filtering out FBNativeAds with invalid URL schemes doesn't seem like a solution.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @PabloMartinez No, not really.

Comment: Are you using the latest facebook ads version? @Mercurial

Comment: @PabloMartinez Yep.

Comment: Not good, I suppose We can't fix as it is a facebook internal crash... @Mercurial